# What is __globals__ and why is it accessible through a class's __init__?

Tags: python, security

I'm reading a book about Python tricks, and I've just encountered this example of a security flaw through string formatting:

```
>>> SECRET = 'this-is-a-secret'
>>> class Error:
...     def __init__(self):
...     pass
>>> err = Error()
>>> user_input = '{error.__init__.__globals__[SECRET]}'
# Uh-oh...
>>> user_input.format(error=err)
'this-is-a-secret'
```

So my questions are what is `__globals__`? And why is it accessible through `Error.__init__`?

Comment: Why do you think this is a security flaw?

Comment: The security flaw is using any user input as the template for `format` or any other formatting functions.

Comment: Python is highly dynamic, almost anything is introspectable, including the global namespace for any function. `__globals__` is simply the reference to the global namespace the function was defined in.

Comment: “..what is `__globals__`..” can be found with trivial searching.  The secondary question is more interesting, and perhaps harder to identify from a simple web search.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, I posted this question mainly for the "why is it accessible" part.

Comment: Focusing on the "mainly" part will generally result in more productive responses.

Comment: eg. "Why is `__globals__` accessible as method property?" (or whatever a specific question is), working to remove all secondary asides. Or if the focus is only on security claims, focus on that etc. Bring some baseline - even if it's an incorrect assertion of a baseline - to questions for focus/validation/correction.